# How to use php code in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a javascript file grid.js that containsthe following code

```
Preview.prototype = {
        create : function() {
            // create Preview structure:
            this.$title = $( '<h3></h3>' );
            this.$description = $( '<p></p>' );
            this.$href = $('<div class="showbutton"><form id="myform" method="POST" action="#"><div class="linkbtn02"><a href="#">EVOEGEN</a></div></form></div>' );
            this.$details = $( '<div class="og-details"></div>' ).append( this.$title, this.$description, this.$href );
            this.$loading = $( '<div class="og-loading"></div>' );
            this.$fullimage = $( '<div class="og-fullimg"></div>' ).append( this.$loading );
            this.$closePreview = $( '<span class="og-close"></span>' );
            this.$previewInner = $( '<div class="og-expander-inner"></div>' ).append( this.$closePreview, this.$fullimage, this.$details );
            this.$previewEl = $( '<div class="og-expander"></div>' ).append( this.$previewInner );
            // append preview element to the item
            this.$item.append( this.getEl() );
            // set the transitions for the preview and the item
            if( support ) {
                this.setTransition();
            }
        },
}
```

But I would like to use dynamic values for `this.$href` attribute.

It will be like this

```
this.$href = $('<div class="showbutton"><?php woocommerce_quantity_input(); ?></div>' );
```

Can someone tell me how to use that inside php?

Please note, I have a foreach loop. So that line will be different for each loop.

Comment: You can't. It is a js file, so you can't have PHP in it. Unless you change you change your file extension to be `.php` or change the way the server handles JS files.

Comment: I know I cannot use php inside external js file.Thats why I asked this question. I meant I would like to use that one line in my php file

Comment: You would need to have your php output the data in a way that allows javascript to loop over it. It is simply impossible to cross client and server code like you are asking.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing preventing your from doing `<script src="myfile.php"></script>` and having your PHP code dynamically generate JS. Don't forget to begin with `header('Content-Type: text/javascript')`.

Comment: @everyone Ok guys.. I end up using ajax. I thank you all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you can do is pass the variable from outside that `.js` file, like this:

```
// index.php

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns">
        page content
    </div>
</div>
<script>var test = '<?php echo $variable; ?>';</script>
```

and then reference that variable the same as if you defined it within that `.js` file (mind the potential scope issue).

Comment: This is way easier than changing the `.JS` file to `.PHP` file and having your `PHP` code dynamically generate `JS` code, BUT... this is way less secure since anyone can change the value of that `JS` variable easily with the power of the browser's `DevTool`.